# How do I prove that the sum: $1/\ln(n)^p$ diverges for $p>1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

So I need to prove that the infinite sum $\frac{1}{(\ln(n)^p)}$ diverges for all values of $p$. I managed to prove it for $p\leq 1$ via comparison test with $1/n$. but for this I can't seem to find a way to prove it diverges for $p>1$.

Comment: $\sum_{n= 2^k}^{2^{k+1}} \ln^p( n) \approx \sum_{n= 2^k}^{2^{k+1}} \ln^p( 2^k) =2^k k^p \ln^p (2)$

Answer (score 2):

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality that the logarithm function satisfies the inequalities

$$\frac{x-1}{x}\le \log(x)\le x-1 <x\tag 1$$

for $0<x$.

---

Using the property $\log(x^a)=a\log(x)$ in $(1)$, we obtain for $a>0$

$$\log(x)<\frac{x^a}{a}\tag2 $$

For $x>n>1$, we have from $(2)$

$$\frac{1}{\log^p(n)}>\frac{a}{n^{ap}}\tag 1$$

For any $p>1$, we can take $a=1/p$ so that $ap=1$.  Hence, the series $\sum_{n=1}\frac{1}{\log^p(n)}$ dominates the series, $\frac1p\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$, which diverges.  The comparison test guarantees that the series $\sum_{n=1}\frac{1}{\log^p(n)}$ diverges also.

Comment: One typo, but otherwise great!  [Note:  (2) $\Rightarrow$ $(\log(x))^p < (\frac{x^a}{a})^p =\frac{x^{ap}}{a^p}$  so putting $a=1/p$ gives $(\log(x))^p < \frac{x}{(\frac{1}{p})^p}$.  Rearranging/taking reciprocals gives $(\frac{1}{p})^p(\frac{1}{x})<(\frac{1}{\log(x)})^p$ $\Rightarrow \frac{1}{p^p}\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{\log^p(n)}$.]

Answer (score 1):

Use that for $n$ large enough $\ln^p n < n$ and compare your series with $\sum 1/n$.

Comment: i will be required to explain why that statement  is true, so just to make sure im correct, i can prove that the limit of n/(ln(n)^p) goes to infinity and from that i can derive this statement?

Comment: @dvd280, apply L'Hôpital repeatedly or Cesaro-Stolz.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove it using the following theorem

> **Theorem (the integral test):** Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function of real numbers that is monotonic decreasing. Then for any $N\in\mathbb N$, $\sum_{n=N}^\infty f(n)$ converges if and only if $\int_N^\infty f(x)dx$ is finite.

Comment: I cant use it to prove stuff yet since we havent proven that theorem yet in class unfortunately.Thanks though!